# trigger execution error(Duplicate id in list)

Tags: trigger

I wrote a trigger that works when adding a single object, but when adding an array with the same id, it gives an error

first error:

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, PaymentUpdate: execution of BeforeInsert
> caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:
> 0065j000002ZSWRAA4\n\nTrigger.PaymentUpdate: line 51, column 1: []

Comment: I think you might have a typo in your Paymant__c object name. If it's supposed to be English than it should be Payment

Comment: @Kasper no typo, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is straightforward. You cannot perform a DML update using a list that uses a single record Id (by which I specifically mean the standard `Id` field) more than once.

Since your `Paymant__c` records can point to the same Opportunity, you need to do something yourself to guarantee that you won't end up with a list that contains the same Opportunity more than once.

Probably the simplest way to do this is to use a Map instead of a List. If you `put()` into a map where the key already exists in the map, you'll overwrite the current value associated with that key (instead of getting a duplicate entry).

When it comes time to perform the DML update, you'd do that by getting the values of the map, e.g. `update myMap.values();`.

That should get you through your current issue, but there are other things you should take into consideration.

- Yes, it's not required to use curly braces with `if` statements, but leaving them out is bad practice (harder to read, easier to make a scoping mistake)
- For most intents and purposes, DML should never appear inside of a loop
- Your code assumes that you're only ever working with `Paymant__c` records related to a single Opportunity. You probably want to end up putting the `AggregateResult` records into a Map keyed on the Opportunity Id.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm a beginner developer, could you please demonstrate this in code so that I can figure it out?

Comment: @AppDetail I encourage you to give it a try yourself first based on what I've written so far. Especially the bit about replacing your opportunity list (oppToUpdate) with a map. It'd be hard to write a meaningful example without simply providing a copy/paste solution.